# make the whole page scroll beneath a certain height at the top without any scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html:

```
<div class="div_fixed"></div>

<div class="other_content">

content goes here
</div>
```

css:

```
.div_fixed{
position:fixed;
height:40px;

}

.other_content{

height:200px;

}
```

The `div_fixed` will remain fixed at the top position of the page.

But as the page scrolls up, the content of the div `other_content` will vanish just at  the lower edge of the div `div_fixed` .

In the case of scrolling down the invisible content of `other_content` will begin to be visible from the lower edge of the `div_fixed`

How to achieve that ?

**EDIT:** no scroll bar should appear for any div

Comment: just made the other_content div's css property - overflow-y:scroll. which obviously did not serve my purpose as I do not want any scroll bar. see my edit please

Comment: I've taken your code and put it in a jsfiddle for you, but for future reference, Javascript questions are very much helped by putting them in a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow: hidden` to get rid of scrollbars

Comment: so will the upper edge of other_content will vanish beneath the div_fixed or at the top of the page overlapping the later div's content?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your HTML/CSS and added a bit on a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3cta/2/) - I think in order to achieve the effect you're looking for, you just need to make your content actually tall enough to be scrollable.  At 200px high and one line of text, nothing is going to scroll.

So I made your `other_content` div taller, and then added a `top: 0` to your `.div_fixed` selector, to keep it stuck to the top of the screen, and a `margin-top: 40px` to the `.other_content` div in order to have it start below the floating div.

If you want it to be a navbar-type thing, you can of course add a `width: 100%` to the `.div_fixed`.

All of this should transfer into a container div (with `position: relative`) fairly easily as well if you want, although you may have to re-position the fixed div.

Comment: your jsfiddle shows very strange output. Did you find  the output I am looking for there ?

Comment: waiting to hear from you please

Comment: I didn't link to the latest jsfiddle, but mine is a basic version of what Phortuin added below, with the 100% width that I mentioned.

Comment: ah I see, biggest difference is the height of your content div :) I put it on 5000 or so on purpose to show the effect.

Comment: @cincodenada, 'latest jsfiddle' ? I rechecked your fiddle again and found that the content vanishes at the top of the page, not at the bottom of the div_fixed div

Comment: I'm using the same technique as Phortuin below, he just stretched the div all the way across so it disappears behind the div.  I've modified my jsFiddle to do the same, but Phortuin and I are basically doing the same thing.  If you add a "visibility: hidden" to the .div_fixed on his example, you'll see it's doing the same thing as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/BCRPa/

Comment: most probably, let me test finally

Comment: so tour main technique is to make the padding-top of other_content equal to the height of div_fixed, right?

Comment: Yes, I used padding but there are other ways to do it; the point is that a `position:fixed` element doesn't push other elements down, so you need to make sure that the flowing element (content) appears below the fixed element.